# Storing values from SQL tables into different PHP arrays

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

In my course_status table. I have 3 columns(course_name, course_status, student_id). When I searched for a student id, the course_name cell table should change according to the status. 
This is the query I am using to get pending, completed and incomplete courses into my arrays.

```
$done_course = array();
$progress_course = array();
$pending_course = array();
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval2)){
        if($row2['course_status'] = 'pending') {
                $pending = True; 
                array_push($pending_course, $row2['course_name']);}
         if($row2['course_status'] = 'In_progress')  {
                $progress = True;                                                 
                 array_push($progress_course,$row2['course_name']); } 
          if($row2['course_status'] = 'done') {
                 $done = True; 
                 array_push($done_course, $row2['course_name']); }
```

My question is when I run the code $done_courses will store all courses including pending and incomplete. How do I prevent it and make it only store completed courses?

Comment: So what is the question? You need to show us more detail e.g. how you output the cell table, and how you want to change it dependent on the status.

Comment: @Nick, I use js to output the cell but I just need to fogure how to get the courses into the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My question is when I run the code $done_courses will store all courses including pending and incomplete.**

I don't think this was printing mistake `if($row2['course_status'] = 'pending') {` you are comparing with single `=` instead of `==`

Once you change this `=` to this `==` it will work fine...